# IndexError: list index out of range - Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, csv

I'm currently testing my program which is basically meant to read and write to a 'stock' file using the CSV module in python. However I am getting this error:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

The error comes from this part of the program:

```
def GTIN8Test(): # function validates GTIN
digit8 = input("Please enter the GTIN-8 of the product you want to modify in the stock file: ") # input for GTIN
while digit8.isdigit is False or len(digit8) > 8 or len(digit8) < 8: # checks length of GTIN and characters
    digit8 = input("Invalid GTIN-8! Please enter a valid GTIN ")
V1 = int(digit8[0])
V2 = int(digit8[1])
V3 = int(digit8[2])
V4 = int(digit8[3]) # validates GTIN
V5 = int(digit8[4])
V6 = int(digit8[5])
V7 = int(digit8[6])
V8 = int(digit8[7])
V1a = V1 * 3
V3a = V3 * 3
V5a = V5 * 3
V7a = V7 * 3
T1 = V1a + V2 + V3a + V4 + V5a + V6 + V7a + V8 
T2 = T1 % 10
if T2 != 0:
    print("Your GTIN-8 code",digit8,"is not valid!")
    GTIN8Test() # calls function so user can enter another GTIN if theirs is invalid
else:
    import csv # imports CSV for reading files
    s = open("stock.txt") # opens stock file
    counter = 0 # sets counter to 0
    while counter != 3: # while counter is not = to 3 this loop keeps running
        for stock in csv.reader(s): # checks each line in the stock file6
            if digit8 == stock[0]:
                print("GTIN-8 is valid and is found in the stock file")
                StockMod(digit8) # StockMod is called, carring the GTIN as a paramter
            else:
                counter = counter + 1 # if no matches on a line are found 1 is added to the counter. 
    print("GTIN valid but not found in stock file!") # message displays when counter = 3.
    s.close() # closes stock file
```

And the error seems to be triggered at the end of this function:

```
def StockMod(digit8): # function which modifies the stock file, digit8 taken as a paramter
import csv # imports CSV to read and write
StockFile = [] # creates stock file list
s = open("stock.txt") # opens stock file
for stock in csv.reader(s): # checks each line in the stock file
    if digit8 == stock[0]: # if the GTIN matches another GTIN in the stock file
        print(digit8, "is assigned to", stock[1], "and has", stock[2], "in stock with a target stock level of", stock[4])
        quantity = input("Please enter quantity") # asks user for quantity
        newq = int(quantity) + int(stock[2]) # calculates the new quantity of the product chosen by the user
        stock[2] = newq # changes the quantity in the file to the new one
    StockFile.append(stock) # appends the list stockfile with the information gathered by the program         
s.close() # closes the file
print(StockFile) # prints stockfile list
s = open("stock.txt", "wt", newline = "") # opens the stock file again for writing
writer = csv.writer(s) # sets up csv to write
for product in StockFile: # goes through each line in the stockfile list
    writer.writerow(product) # writes everything back into the stock file
s.close() # closes the stock file
print("File write success")
```

Sorry if there are any formatting errors!

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here is the full error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mavro\Documents\School Work\GCSE COURSEWORK\Computer Science\Task 3\Task3MOD (1).py", line 84, in <module>
    GTIN8Test() # calls GTIN8Test for StockMod
  File "C:\Users\Mavro\Documents\School Work\GCSE COURSEWORK\Computer Science\Task 3\Task3MOD (1).py", line 29, in GTIN8Test
    if digit8 == stock[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Please give the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Hi, i just added it.

Comment: You should check the output for each line of  `for stock in csv.reader(s):`. `stock[0]` seems to throw your error. Perhaps there are empty lines in your input document?!

Comment: Also, fix `while digit8.isdigit is False` to `while digit8.isdigit() is False`, perhaps.

Comment: Changing `.isdigit` to `.isdigit()` seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the "stock.txt" look like? Maybe you have empty line at the beginning of the file? csv.reader would return empty list in that case. in that case you can add s.readline() before this line:

```
for stock in csv.reader(s):
```

you can also check each line if it's not empty:

```
if stock != []:
```